# How do I declare a recursive Map type in Typescript (TS2456: Type alias '*' circularly references itself.)

Tags: typescript

I wish to define a `Map` variable that should hold either a primitive value (string | number | boolean) or another `Map` of the same type.

I've tried to do this:

```
type Primitive = string | number | boolean;
type SafeNestedMap = Map<string, Primitive | SafeNestedMap>;
let states: SafeNestedMap = new Map<string, SafeNestedMap>();
```

however the compiler complains:

```
TS2456: Type alias 'SafeNestedMap' circularly references itself.
```

How can i properly declare this recursive type?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are some extremely subtle details around how `interface` and `type`s are different in TypeScript; one caveat of type aliases is that they may not be self-referential (this is because they are immediately expanded, whereas interfaces are expanded later).

You can instead write

```
interface SafeNestedMap extends Map<string, Primitive | SafeNestedMap> { }
```